# How would I swap 2 letters in a java string using toCharArray()?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, debugging, swap

I want `ab` to be returned as `ba` but my output is `a a`.  I understand why I get that output.  If `a[i] < a[j]` (if 1st index < 2nd index, which is true because a < b, then replace b (`a[j]`) with a (`a[i]`)).

I just can't wrap my head around how I would go about swapping those two letters with arrays.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
public static void solution(String A) {
    char[] a = A.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if(a[i] < a[j]) {
                a[j] = a[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String A = "ab";

    solution(A);
}
```

Comment: to swap like that, you need a temporary place holder to store a[j] , when you update a[j] with a[i], then you re-assign that temporarily stored value to a[i] to complete the swap

Comment: As strings are immutable, any attempt to do this will not actually swap character in the original string. `toCharArray` returns a **new** array with the characters in the string. Modifying that array will not affect the original string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a temporary variable and place `a[j]` in it, then override `a[j]` with `a[i]` and finally override `a[i]` with the old value of `a[j]` you stored in the temporary variable:

```
if (a[i] < a[j]) {
    char temp = a[j];
    a[j] = a[i];
    a[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you really want to create a temp to store your character, BUT if you're trying to write less code and don't care about performance, you can even just reverse the string in your case, instead of using toCharArray, using java's StringBuilder package

```
    import java.lang.*;

    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder;
    input.append(A);
    input = input.reverse();
    System.out.print(input);
```